# ContextMenuStrip submenu position (C#, Win Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

i have a two level ContextMenuStrip which open by a NofiyIcon right click. I create this menu in code.

```
menuitem1 --- submenu1
          --- submenu2
          --- submenu3
menuitem2 --- submenu1
          --- submenu2
          --- submenu3
........
```

Everything is fine but the submenus open in wrong position (at the top of main menu). I want to open at main menu items position.

Like this:

[image]

So how can i control the submenus position? Relevant code:

```
tray_menu_item = new ToolStripMenuItem(); 
tray_menu_item.Text = kvp.Value.ToString(); 
while (reader.Read()) { 
   tray_menu_subitem = new ToolStripMenuItem(); 
   tray_menu_subitem.Text = reader["task"].ToString(); 
   ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)tray_menu_subitem.DropDown).ShowImag‌​eMargin = false; 
   tray_menu_item.DropDownItems.Add(tray_menu_subitem);
} 

tray_menu.Items.Add(tray_menu_item);
```

Comment: Your question does not have code which reproduces problem

Comment: How can i edit my question? Ok, i see.

Comment: @kovak: Press `Ctrl + F` in browser and search `edit`. ;)

Comment: That is not the "wrong position".  A submenu should be placed so that the odds that the user loses it accidentally when moving the mouse cursor from the main menu to the submenu are minimized.  If you ever used UI that got this wrong like VLC player (submenus too small) or a web page (submenus placed wrong) you know how painful it can be.  ToolStripMenuItem does not have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this [Show(Point)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz0wbhy2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
cmsInventory.Show(cmsInventory.PointToScreen(p));
```

Or you could use [Show(Control, Point)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71tzk45y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload to position the contextmenustrip relative to the specified control location.